Images not rendering after deploying React project on Netlify
I've deployed my React project to Netlify, but the images aren’t rendering on the live site. I tried deploying both from GitHub and manually. The project was created with Vite, and based on forum suggestions, I moved the images to the public folder, but that didn’t help.

GitHub Repo
Netlify Site

When I run npm run build, the images appear in the dist folder as expected. Any advice on what could be causing this issue?

The public folder is served as static so at build time the contents of public are moved to the root of the build output (dist). The fix would be to use absolute path for the assets, for example, I found in your code this:
<div className="comment__card-section1">
    <div className="comment__card-img1-container">
        <img src="../../public/images/icon-plus.svg" alt="icon-plus" />
    </div>
    <span className="comment__card-number">{score}</span>
    <div className="comment__card-img1-container">
        <img src="../../public/images/icon-minus.svg" alt="icon-minus" />
    </div>
</div>

change it to this:
<div className="comment__card-section1">
    <div className="comment__card-img1-container">
        <img src="/images/icon-plus.svg" alt="icon-plus" />
    </div>
    <span className="comment__card-number">{score}</span>
    <div className="comment__card-img1-container">
        <img src="/images/icon-minus.svg" alt="icon-minus" />
    </div>
</div>

This will not work in dev, so i think the way to fix this is use the BASE_URL offered by vite (import.meta.env.BASE_URL) and make it something like:
<div className="comment__card-section1">
    <div className="comment__card-img1-container">
        <img src=`${import.meta.env.BASE_URL}images/icon-plus.svg` alt="icon-plus" />
    </div>
    <span className="comment__card-number">{score}</span>
    <div className="comment__card-img1-container">
        <img src=`${import.meta.env.BASE_URL}images/icon-minus.svg` alt="icon-minus" />
    </div>
</div>

Something similar to this, haven't tested it but should work.

This did work   thanks for the help
